# Slow XML import with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a XML file with a size of 1GB.
I use the following code to load the data into sql server.

```
DECLARE @xmlvar XML
SELECT @xmlvar = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Data\demo.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver',
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:move' AS ns4,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:cat:fill' as ns3,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:centre' as ns2)
SELECT

        zs.value(N'(../@versionCode)', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode,
        zs.value(N'(@Start)', 'VARCHAR(50)') as Start_date,
        zs.value(N'(@End)', 'VARCHAR(50)') as End_date

into testtbl

FROM @xmlvar.nodes('/ns4:Dataview1/ns4:Content/ns4:gen') A(zs);
```

I takes now more than 2 hours to run the query and it is not finished.
I have tested the query with a smaller version of the XML file and that works.
Any tips on improving the loading speed?

Thank you.

**Update XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:Dataview1 xmlns="ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver" xmlns:ns4="ux:no:ehe:v5:move">
    <ns4:Content versionCode="16000">
        <ns4:gen start="1961-07-01" end="1961-07-01">            
        </ns4:gen>
        <ns4:gen start="2017-09-19">            
        </ns4:gen>
        <ns4:gen start="1961-07-02" end="2016-09-30">           
        </ns4:gen>
        <ns4:gen start="2016-10-01" end="2017-09-18">            
        </ns4:gen>      
    </ns4:Content>
  </ns4:Dataview1>
```

Comment: Maybe try loading the file directly into a staging table first before then selecting your xml transformations from the staging table.

Comment: Try running from command line utility sqlcmd.exe which comes with sqlserver:  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I think you are going to need a different tool for this. Perhaps use C#/Powershell with `XmlTextReader` to break down the XML, and maybe `SqlBulkCopy` to stream the data into SQL Server.

Comment: There are scenarios where OPENXML is faster, but XmlReader+SqlBulkCopy will always be the fastest.  XmlReader can be daunting.  The key is to just target the Elements with XmlReader, then use .ReadSubTree and pass that to XElement.Load https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.load?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) As @Stu already pointed out, loading XML file first into a single row table will speed up the process of loading significantly.

(2) it is not a good idea to traverse XML up in the XPath expressions. Like here:

```
c.value('../@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode
```

But the XML structure was not shared in the question. So, it is impossible to suggest anything concrete.

2nd `CROSS APPLY` is simulating 1-to-many relationship in the XML hierarchy.

Check it out below.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Data\demo.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver',
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:move' AS ns4,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:cat:fill' as ns3,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:centre' as ns2)
SELECT c.value('@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode,
    x.value('@start', 'DATE') as Start_date,
    x.value('@end', 'DATE') as End_date
INTO dbo.testtbl
FROM tbl
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/ns4:Dataview1/ns4:Content') AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY t1.c.nodes('ns4:gen') AS t2(x);
```

Comment: Hi, I have applied your suggestion. Qry is now stil running after 2 hours. Initial qry was running all night and did not finish, because i cancelled it.

Comment: Are you getting just 3 attributes, or your real life query is more complicated?

Comment: Only 3 attributes for testing, it still runs > 11hours

Comment: Please try to use a real table instead of table variable. Also, what about (2) ?

Comment: If i remove this line: "c.value('../@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode"  
Qry finish in 10 seconds. This line is the versionidentifier.

Comment: (2) was in my answer from the very beginning. Please add to your original question XML sample. I will show how to deal with the `@versionCode` properly.

Comment: I have added the XML sample.

Comment: Sample XML has both @start and @end attributes as lower-case. I adjusted the `SELECT ...` statement accordingly.

Comment: Great! Reduced time to 39 seconds.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to use an SSIS Package for importing XML files.
It has a component named "XML Source" for loading XML file.

There is a useful article at : https://www.sqlshack.com/import-xml-documents-into-sql-server-tables-using-ssis-packages/

Comment: Normally I import xml with SSIS, but this one is to complex. Therefore i am trying to get the import with a query.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this runs any faster as this seems to be the problem to be solved.