# Don't understand XML load into SQL database

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have the following XML file which i want to load into SQL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:Dataview1 xmlns="ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver" xmlns:ns4="ux:no:ehe:v5:move"  xmlns:ns2="ux:no:ehe:v5:centre" xmlns:ns5="ux:no:ehe:v5:tran">
  <ns4:Content versionCode="16000">
    <ns4:gen start="1961-07-01" end="1961-07-01">
    </ns4:gen>
      <Weight unit="KG">30.0000</Weight>
    <ns4:gen start="2017-09-19">
    </ns4:gen>
    <ns4:gen start="1961-07-02" end="2016-09-30">
      <ns5:translation>
        <ns2:En>Example Data English 234354</ns2:En>
      </ns5:translation>
      <Type>Circle</Type>
      <Weight unit="KG">10.0000</Weight>
    </ns4:gen>
    <ns4:gen start="2016-10-01" end="2017-09-18">
      <ns5:translation>
        <ns2:De>Beispieldaten Deutschland 23443</ns2:De>
        <ns2:En>Example Data English 23443</ns2:En>
      </ns5:translation>
      <Weight unit="KG">20.0000</Weight>
    </ns4:gen>
  </ns4:Content>
</ns4:Dataview1>
```

Following code is used:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Data\demoset.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  'ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver',
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:tran' as ns5,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:move' AS ns4,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:cat:fill' as ns3,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:centre' as ns2)

SELECT   c.value('@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode,
         x.value('@start', 'DATE') as Start_date,
         x.value('@end', 'DATE') as End_date,
         x.value('(ns5:translation/ns2:En)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Trans_EN,
         x.value('Type[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Typed,
         x.value('(Weight/unit)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Unitdata,
         x.value('Weight[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Weightdata
INTO dbo.testtbl
FROM tbl
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/ns4:Dataview1/ns4:Content') AS t1(c)
    OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('ns4:gen') AS t2(x);
```

I have three questions:

1.) I don't understand why it is not possible to use @ns2:En, @Type, @Weight.
Therefore, why do i need to place [1] behind data ns2:En, Type & Weight?

2.) Why is '(Weight/unit)[1]' not working?

3.) If I change outer apply to cross apply results are the same. I think i need to use outer apply since it is a left outer join in my opinion, but I don't understand completely. In my previous topic cross apply is used in the answer.
[Slow XML import with SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092800/slow-xml-import-with-sql-server/73095332#73095332)

Comment: It should be `Weight/@unit`, you aren't looking for the node `unit`, you want the property.

Comment: "x.value('Weight/@unit', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Unitdata": gives the following error:
Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
XQuery [tbl.XmlColumn.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: You removed the singleton, as the error tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. - `.value` always needs a singleton: in other words it must be *statically* known (upfront) that there will be exactly one node to retrieve. This is normally done using a predicate `[1]` to retrieve the first node.
   - Retrieving a whole node  using `.value` implicitly takes the `text()` node (of which there may be more than one), however it is better and more performant to specify it explicitly like `(Type/text())[1]`
   - In the case of attributes (see 2.),  there is always one unique attribute, so this doesn't need `[1]`. But this only applies if you are retrieving a top-level attribute. If you go down a level then you may have multiple attributes, again requiring `[1]`.
2. Attributes are retrieved using `@`, so you need `(Weight/@unit)[1]`.
3. The `.nodes` function shreds the XML into separate rows. `CROSS APPLY` implies that you expect rows and to act like an `INNER JOIN`, whereas `OUTER APPLY` implies that there may not be rows but you still want nulls, like a `LEFT JOIN`. Up to you as to what you expect.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  'ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver',
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:tran' as ns5,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:move' AS ns4,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:cat:fill' as ns3,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:centre' as ns2)

SELECT   c.value('@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode,
         x.value('@start', 'DATE') as Start_date,
         x.value('@end', 'DATE') as End_date,
         x.value('(ns5:translation/ns2:En/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Trans_EN,
         x.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Typed,
         x.value('(Weight/@unit)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Unitdata,
         x.value('(Weight/text())[1]', 'decimal(18,9)') as Weightdata
FROM tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.XmlColumn.nodes('/ns4:Dataview1/ns4:Content') AS t1(c)
    OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('ns4:gen') AS t2(x);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a2e572280d72cc5177c81ddb7defe68)

You don't *need* to create a table just to use `OPENROWSET`, you can feed it straight in:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  'ux:no::ehe:v5:actual:aver',
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:tran' as ns5,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:move' AS ns4,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:cat:fill' as ns3,
                            'ux:no:ehe:v5:centre' as ns2)

SELECT   c.value('@versionCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') as versionCode,
         x.value('@start', 'DATE') as Start_date,
         x.value('@end', 'DATE') as End_date,
         x.value('(ns5:translation/ns2:En/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Trans_EN,
         x.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Typed,
         x.value('(Weight/@unit)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Unitdata,
         x.value('(Weight/text())[1]', 'decimal(18,9)') as Weightdata
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Data\demoset.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS blk(col)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
        CAST(blk.col AS xml)
    ) ) AS t(XmlColumn)
    CROSS APPLY t.XmlColumn.nodes('/ns4:Dataview1/ns4:Content') AS t1(c)
    OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('ns4:gen') AS t2(x);
```